# How to execute javascript function on href tags through URL in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, popup, fancybox

Actual scenario:

1. user click on button 'Jana Laporan', (in case, input field was left empty)
2. javascript function execute, but it is return to another VIEW.

Supposed to be, once user clicked on button with left empty its input field, the javascript function remains stay the same VIEW.

Here are my Javascript Function:

```
function validateInput() {
 var strStartDate = document.ReportSearchForm.StartDate.value;
 var strEndDate = document.ReportSearchForm.EndDate.value;
 var strDptId = document.ReportSearchForm.searchDptId.value;

  if (strStartDate == "" && strEndDate == "") {
     alert("Tarikh (Mula) dan Tarikh (Akhir) dikehendaki.");
     document.ReportSearchForm.strStartDate.focus();
     return false;
  }
  else if ((strStartDate != "" && strEndDate == "") || (strStartDate == "" && strEndDate != "")) {
      alert("Tarikh (Mula) atau Tarikh (Akhir) dikehendaki.");
      return false;
  }
  else if (strDptId == "") {
      alert("Jawatankuasa dikehendaki.");
      return false;
  } }
```

Here my button in form :

```
<a id="transboxShow" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="{{ URL::to('laporanjumlahmesyuaratresult/sujk?t=2')}}">{{ Form::button('Jana Laporan', array('name'=>'btnAdd', 'onclick'=>'return validateInput(); return false;','class'=>'NormalTextCenter', 'data-fancybox-type'=>'iframe') ) }}</a>
```

how can I execute javascript function through fancybox popup that validate my input field in same VIEW without go to the next url/VIEW ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your javascript function on onclick attribute of the anchor tag like this below.

```
<a id="transboxShow" onclick="return validateInput()" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="{{ URL::to('laporanjumlahmesyuaratresult/sujk?t=2')}}">{{ Form::button('Jana Laporan', array('name'=>'btnAdd', 'onclick'=>'return validateInput(); return false;','class'=>'NormalTextCenter', 'data-fancybox-type'=>'iframe') ) }}</a>
```

Doing so, when you click on the anchor tag(or the button inside it), it will first execute your 'validateInput' function and if the function returns false, it will not proceed with normal link action otherwise it will go to the link you specified.

**Another approach** could be prevent the default link action and then change your code inside the 'validateInput' function to redirect to the url(where your anchor tag currently pointing to) if it validates to true.

To disable the anchor tag:

```
$("#transboxShow").off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
)}
```

and your changed function would be look like this:

```
function validateInput(newLocation) {
 var strStartDate = document.ReportSearchForm.StartDate.value;
 var strEndDate = document.ReportSearchForm.EndDate.value;
 var strDptId = document.ReportSearchForm.searchDptId.value;

  if (strStartDate == "" && strEndDate == "") {
     alert("Tarikh (Mula) dan Tarikh (Akhir) dikehendaki.");
     document.ReportSearchForm.strStartDate.focus();
     return false;
  }
  else if ((strStartDate != "" && strEndDate == "") || (strStartDate == "" && strEndDate != "")) {
      alert("Tarikh (Mula) atau Tarikh (Akhir) dikehendaki.");
      return false;
  }
  else if (strDptId == "") {
      alert("Jawatankuasa dikehendaki.");
      return false;
  } 
  //if all validation passed, redirect to your desired location
   window.location = newLocation;
}
```

Then change  the 'validateInput' function to call with a parameter for your new url like below:

```
<a id="transboxShow" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="#">
{{ Form::button('Jana Laporan', array('name'=>'btnAdd', 'onclick'=>'return validateInput(URL::to('laporanjumlahmesyuaratresult/sujk?t=2')); return false;','class'=>'NormalTextCenter', 'data-fancybox-type'=>'iframe') ) }}
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is inside an `<a>` tag that is why when you click the button, it is going to the url you provided on href attribute. You can move the validation on the onclick attribute of the hyperlink.

```
<a id="transboxShow" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="{{ URL::to('laporanjumlahmesyuaratresult/sujk?t=2')}}" onclick="return validateInput();" >
    {{ Form::button('Jana Laporan', array('name'=>'btnAdd', 'class'=>'NormalTextCenter', 'data-fancybox-type'=>'iframe') ) }}
</a>
```

or you can remove the button at all. Im not sure why you have a button inside an `<a>` tag.

Comment: thanks for your answered. However, I already tried but it's doesn't work.